# Screen totally scrambled when wake from suspend?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display, screen

I'm having a new problem all of a sudden where when Ubuntu 18.04 wakes up from suspend/sleep, [the screen will turn totally scrambled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wlV2.jpg). This has not happened before and just started today. There are no problems when booting up and using Ubuntu, as it only occurs when waking. Furthermore, I have Windows installed on another hard drive and am able to boot and wake from it properly.

I use an NVIDIA GTX 1060, which I'm aware has had some driver issues before and caused scrambled screens. However, other posts seem to have at least some legibility on the screen (and it mostly seems to be rendering on the border of windows), but in my case there is absolutely nothing recognizable, so I don't know if it is the same problem.

I tried refreshing the screen using `alt + F2 + r + enter`. I can confirm that it ran since my mouse pointer will refresh to the middle of the screen, but nothing else changes. I also tried changing my driver from 390.48 to the default nouveau one on the system, and also uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers. I thought the driver issue was fixed before 390 so I'm not sure if that's the problem, plus I was able to wake from sleep without any problems just yesterday. I also tried using compiz to use the Workaround "Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint" but that didn't help either.

Is there a way to fix this issue, or at least a way to debug it?